# Qt 5.7 How can I check value of variable QT_QPA_PLATFORM at runtime?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, wayland, qt5.7

I know how to check default platform, but I need to check in my application if it run on X11 or Wayland. I try this:

```
QString platform = qgetenv("QT_QPA_PLATFORM");
```

but it returns an empty string.

On Weston when I run my application I set QT_QPA_PLATFORM to Wayland:

```
./myApp -platform wayland
```

but my QString platform is still empty, and default platform name doesn't change either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`QGuiApplication::platformName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#platformName-prop).